# Rewrite condition to match ANY file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

What this does is insert a trailing slash character to all my URLs, i.e:

`http://localhost/advertising` becomes `http://localhost/advertising/`

Now I have some URLs such as: `http://localhost/contact.html`

But my htaccess rule is applying the slash to these URLs too - so the above URL becomes `http://localhost/contact.html/`

Now I added the following condition to prevent this happening:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|php)$
```

But I want to be a bit more clever than this - I want a single expression that will match ANY extension the user types in. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't you just using mod_dir and `DirectorySlash On`?

Comment: @JonLin I think that directive doesn't work for non-existing directories!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rewrite all directories without trailing slash!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(.*)(\..{3,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, that solves the file extension problem but it now does not add the trailing slash to non-file URLs, e.g. `http://localhost/advertising`

Comment: you mean all URLs without extension should have a trailing slash?

Comment: Yep :) that's what I was trying to achieve with my original code - I did not realise it would also rewrite URLs with a file extension present.

Comment: @GSTAR I edited my answer! it covers files with extensions with 3-5 chars length

Comment: Cheers mate... seems to be working well! What are the two dots in the bracket for btw?

Comment: `\.`  means dot itself , and second dot means any characters! `{3,5}` defines the length of those characters!